# Save and Append an Array in UserDefaults from ImagePickerControllerImageURL in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm having an issue saving and retrieving an array in UserDefaults from UIImagePickerControllerImageURL. I can get the array after synchronizing, but I am unable to retrieve it. myArray is empty.

The testImage.image does get the image, no problems there.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let imageURL: URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as! URL

    //test that imagepicker is actually getting the image
    let imageData: NSData = try! NSData(contentsOf: imageURL)
    let cvImage = UIImage(data:imageData as Data)
    testImage.image = cvImage

    //Save array to UserDefaults and add picked image url to the array
    let usD = UserDefaults.standard
    var array: NSMutableArray = []
    usD.set(array, forKey: "WeatherArray")
    array.add(imageURL)
    usD.synchronize()
    print ("array is \(array)")

    let myArray = usD.stringArray(forKey:"WeatherArray") ?? [String]()
    print ("myArray is \(myArray)")

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issue here.

1. Do not use `NSData`, use `Data`.
2. Do not use `NSMutableArray`, use a Swift array.
3. You can get the `UIImage` directly from the `info` dictionary`.
4. You can't store URLs in `UserDefaults`.
5. You save `array` to `UserDefaults` before you update the array with the new URL.
6. You create a new array instead of getting the current array from `UserDefaults`.
7. You needlessly call `synchronize`.
8. You needlessly specify the type for most of your variables.

Here is your code updated to fix all of these issues:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        testImage.image = image
    }

    if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {
        //Save array to UserDefaults and add picked image url to the array
        let usD = UserDefaults.standard
        var urls = usD.stringArray(forKey: "WeatherArray") ?? []
        urls.append(imageURL.absoluteString)
        usD.set(urls, forKey: "WeatherArray")
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note that this saves an array of strings representing each URL. Later on, when you access these strings, if you want a `URL`, you need to use `URL(string: arrayElement)`.

Comment: I have a follow-up question regarding accessing the strings. Do you mind taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143229/accessing-userdefault-array-url-to-populate-collectionview) @rmaddy?