# Accessing UserDefault Array URL to Populate CollectionView

Tags: arrays, swift, url, nsuserdefaults

This is a follow-up from a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142238/save-and-append-an-array-in-userdefaults-from-imagepickercontrollerimageurl-in-s).

I am now trying to access the array and use it to populate my collectionView. When I try the following code, my imageData comes back as nil and I get a crash, even though the imageURL correctly shows as a filepath.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let usD = UserDefaults.standard
    let array = usD.stringArray(forKey: "WeatherArray") ?? []

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell

    let myString = array[indexPath.row]
    let imageUrl = URL(string: myString)!
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    cell.myImageView.image = image
```

Here is an example of my URL(string: myString) below:

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6DD4ED20-F1BB-46DB-8A8C-35C3CFB2B2C6/tmp/01431A0E-F7C2-4A60-B1C6-5C9508C75863.jpeg

Also, inspecting imageUrl shows this error:

> Printing description of imageUrl:
>   expression produced error: error: /var/folders/np/4m9vk2yd0bzbf74lxrnffccr0000gn/T/expr9-6d45ad..swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'Foundation'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Foundation.URL>(bitPattern: 0x1054f86a0)!.pointee)

Comment: Your url string points to a temporary file `tmp`. You can't save a reference to a temporary file. If you are willing to load that file later you need to copy/move that file to a directory inside your app sandbox (documents directory)

Comment: Btw you are not saving the URL `path` you are saving its `absoluteString` which it is not the same. It includes the url scheme which forces you to use `URL(string:)` initializer instead of `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`

Comment: What you need to do is to copy/move your image inside imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method before it finishes. Your temporary image it is usually removed when that method finishes executing.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133840/pdfview-does-not-display-my-pdf/48134186?noredirect=1#comment83263434_48134186

Comment: After copying/moving the image you should save its destination url lastPathComponent

Comment: When loading your image you just need to append the file name (lastPathComponent) to your app documentsDirectory url and load your image from the resulting url

Comment: Yes! This helped immensely. Thank you so much @LeoDabus 
For those looking at this, I also used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045948/get-images-from-document-directory-not-file-path-swift-3) to help round out my code.

Comment: Hey all, worked through your comments and got stuck once again, so I have another fun follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164074/populating-collection-view-from-array-in-document-directory-swift) =)