# Populating Collection View from Array in Document Directory

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsfilemanager

This is a follow-up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143229/accessing-userdefault-array-url-to-populate-collectionview). Thanks so much to @rmaddy and @LeoDabus for your help thus far!

**The Good**: my addImage button gets me the correct image in collectionView the first time I pick an image.

**The Bad**: the second time I select an image, it changes both cells to the 2nd image. By the third/fourth/etc times I try to addImage, the image is always the same across each cell no matter what image I choose (i.e. 1st try: image1, 2nd try: image 2, image 2, 3rd try: image 2, image 2, image 2).

**My question**: How do I make the image chosen populate the incremental cells correctly?

Here is my code:

Get the number of cells in the collectionView from count

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let dirContents = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsPath)
    let count = dirContents?.count
    return count!
        }
```

Populate the views

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

    for imageURL in directoryContents where imageURL.pathExtension == "jpeg" {
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
            cell.myImageView.image = image //[indexPath.row] **need "image" to be an array so can assign to indexPath.row
        } else {
            fatalError("Can't create image from file \(imageURL)")
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

addMyImage button opens the imagePicker

```
@IBAction func addMyImage(_ sender: UIButton) {

//imagePickerController stuff
}
```

Save the imageURL in File Manager

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {

    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: imageURL.standardizedFileURL, to: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(imageURL.lastPathComponent))
        collectionView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

After lots of googling, I think the problem is I haven't assigned [indexPath.row] to an array in my cellForItemAt IndexPath, so while the documentDirectory gets updated with the URL, each new cell is not being pointed to the correct URL. Unfortunately, I'm calling a specific URL in that function

```
for imageURL in directoryContents where imageURL.pathExtension == "jpeg"
```

so I am not sure how to assign the indexPath.row...

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Instead of looping in `cellForItemAt`, use `indexPath.item` to index into the `directoryContents` array to select the `imageURL`.  So use  `let imageURL = directoryContents[indexPath.item]`.  Note: `indexPath.item` is the same as `indexPath.row` but the first is for `UICollectionView`s and the second is for `UITableView`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating the **directoryContents**

```
for imageURL in directoryContents where imageURL.pathExtension == "jpeg" {
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
        cell.myImageView.image = image //[indexPath.row] **need "image" to be an array so can assign to indexPath.row
    } else {
        fatalError("Can't create image from file \(imageURL)")
    }
}
```

that's why you only get the last image on all the cells.

What you should do is fetch the directory contents and store it in an array variable (e.g. directoryContentsArray = self.fetchDirectoryContents())

make a function similar to this, and call it on **viewDidLoad**:
this will populate your array.

```
func fetchDirectoryContents() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

    self.directoryContentsArray = directoryContents
    self.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

Then use the array count for numberOfRows and for the datasource as well.
your current design is actually bad right now since you're always calling for FileManager in all your tableView methods

Now, after adding an image successfully and saving it, you will repopulate your array (or you can actually just append it to your existing array)

EDIT: So in your **cellForItem**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? myCell {
       let imageFile = self.directoryContentsArray[indexPath.item]
       if let imageURL = imageFile.path, 
          imageFile.pathExtension == "jpeg",
          let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL) {
          cell.imageView.image = image
       } else {
          fatalError("Can't create image from file \(imageFile)")
       }
    return cell
    }
return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: This is good advice.  Add information to your answer about how to use `indexPath.item` in `cellForItemAt` to get the proper image.

Comment: Really appreciate the comments vacawama and @AceRivera. I get your point that I can create a func fetchDirectoryContents() that gets an array of URLs from the documentsDirectory. I'm not sure how to then use this array to populate the cells correctly... do you mind trying to explain a bit more for me?

Comment: create a local variable "directoryContentsArray" save the directoryContents there you are fetching with fileManager.

Comment: oh and btw, make sure you're only adding images with jpeg to that specific directory.

Comment: A professional touch would be to insert a row to the collectionView instead of calling `reloadData` and reloading all of the images again just because you added one.

Comment: So replace `collectionView.reloadData()` with something like `collectionView.insertItems(at: IndexPath(item: directoryContentsArray.count - 1, section: 0))`.  You should be appending the image to end of `directoryContentsArray` in this case before calling this.

Comment: This is all very helpful, but I am still a bit confused =/

@AceRivera how can I access a local variable without calling the FileManager in each collectionView function? Same for the count... how can I grab a count if I'm not calling the documentsDirectory from FileManager?

Do you mind showing me where I should be creating local variable "directoryContentsArray" exactly?

Comment: If my question is not clear enough, here is a shorter version... you mention: "What you should do is fetch the directory contents and store it in an array variable (e.g. directoryContentsArray = self.fetchDirectoryContents())"

Aren't I already doing this here?
    let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

Comment: Also, when I use your code, I get an error "Static member 'path' cannot be used on instance of type 'String'" because imageFile is a String and not a URL...

Comment: I added the function for fetching the filemanager contents. kindly check.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are really amazing!!!

Btw, I'm getting "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" at the line 

if let imageURL = imageFile.path,

... I copied your code exactly. Do you mind explaining why I get this error?

Comment: I am setting my array variable right after my CollectionViewController class like this:

var directoryContentsArray: [URL] = []

Comment: I'm still confused on this. Is it because I can't have a [URL] as type optional? @vacawama

Comment: Closing the loop. Here is how to fix my optional error: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238003/url-array-throwing-optional-error-swift).